# Get "hidden" value from http reponse in Java

Tags: java, http-post

I'm trying to read HTTP response this way:

```
StringBuffer response;
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
    String inputLine;
    response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
}

System.out.println(response.toString())
```

Everything is ok, but when I display response, there is no "hidden" values.

ex.
When I check site source manually, I get:

```html
<input id="aa" type="hidden" name="aa" value="bbb" />
```

When I get response in Java, I get:

```html
<input id="aa" type="hidden" name="aa" value="" />
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you make sure that the value of the hidden field is passed when http Get/POST submission is made?? If you have Firebug installed on Firefox then you should be able to see the parametres passed and their values. I don't know if I make sense but, all I want to say is that, if you cannot see it in Java then probably it never came with request.

Comment: I have firebug, how can check it? In html tab I can see the value.

Comment: Activate ***Net*** panel, reload the page and then submit your request. There should be an entry for your submission in the Net panel, expand it and then check the ***POST/Params*** tab there and you should see your submission and their name=value ..... http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp (just an example)

Comment: What looks like what happened was that when you loaded the page in Firefox, JavaScript set the attribute of the element after the page loaded. Just getting the raw HTML would not show this. You will need to find where in the code the value is actually sent.

Comment: When I reload the page, there is firefox warning that is has to resend data and after that these values doesn't appear... I need to open it again with button on previous page. So now its clear why there are no values in java response, but the new questions appears, how can I make it working in java. Is it about cookies or smth?